# CSS: How to make all divs change size if one of them was increased in height due to its content?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a component that is made of some divs with a text inside. It's using `overflow-wrap: break-word` property for the text to fit: 
[This  is how it looks like on PC screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7RZ9.png)

But as soon as i shrink screen width, words break and only some of the divs changes its height: [This is how it looks like on small screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vabNC.png)

[HTML markup is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMyUF.png)

The question is how do i make all the divs to change size in this case?

Comment: wrap all the divs with another div and put height 100% of this wrapping div. Then when one will make the wrapping div height greater, all other divs will also grow.

Comment: Also, if you copy the markup and CSS into the question it will make it easier to help you.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please post actual code and not pictures of code - preferably in a working snippet that demonstrates your problem - please see how to create a [mcve].  It would also be beneficial for you to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Hi i suggest to use a table for that

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>
      {firstname} {lastname}
    </td>
    <td>
      {card}
    </td> 
    <td>
      {payed}
    </td>
    <td>
      PDF
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tables should only be used for tabular data and not presentation - this is using it for presentation